# Dictionary typing in python, where the key is called @context

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

How to define a dictionary type with such a structure.

```
result = {"@context": "example_string",
                  "id": "example_string",
                  "type": "example_string",
                  "protocol": "example_string",
                  "profile": "example_string",
                  "width": 0,
                  "height": 0,
                  "maxHeight": 0,
                  "maxWidth": 0,
                  "maxArea": 0}
```

Previously, I defined the type of a similar dictionary as

```
class Result(TypedDict):
    @context: str
    id: str
    type: str
    protocol: str
    profile: str
    width: int
    height: int
    maxHeight: int
    maxWidth: int
    maxArea: int
```

But this time I can't use a variable named `@context` in the class.

Answer (score 1):

You simply cannot use @ in a variable name in python. Only letters numbers and the underscore character are allowed.

There is a workaround, though. You can manually create a TypedDict:

from typing import TypedDict

```
Result = TypedDict('Result', {
                     '@context': str
                     'id': str,
                     'type': str,
                     'protocol': str,
                     'profile': str,
                     'width': int,
                     'height': int,
                     'maxHeight': int,
                     'maxWidth': int,
                     'maxArea': int
})
```

Comment: Maybe there is some other way to define the type without using keys name?